# Font loading CORS problem on Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean

My website is serving fonts (and other assets) externally from a Digital Ocean Spaces bucket, and the CDN is disabled for now. It's a Rails 4 app behind Nginx.

All assets (images, css, js) seem to work fine but not fonts.

After figuring out I had a CORS issue, I added a `https://example.com` CORS configuration in order to allow the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header through for `GET` requests.

It seems to have fixed the issue on Firefox and Safari but I am still getting the following error on Chrome and Opera:

> Access to font at 'https://bucket.region.digitaloceanspaces.com/path-to-fonts/font.ttf' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Does anyone know what could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured! Had to clear Chrome's browsing data.